# Unique Integer Value

Tags: ios, swift

I need a way to generate unique integer values in swift

```
//string
let g = NSUUID().UUIDString
```

How can I accomplish the above in int format?

Comment: If you want a random integer, check out the `arc4random` family of functions. If you want unique integers for successive calls, you have 2 options: (1) keep looping so you don't repeat a previously generated value and (2) randomly shuffle an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UUIDs are, I believe, 16 bytes long. That is big enough to create values that are almost certainly unique. For comparison, Swift `Ints` are 64 bits (8 bytes.)

`Int(rand())` (Or the more "Swifty" `Int.random(in:)`, which also lets you specify a range for your random numbers) will give you random numbers, but not unique random numbers. There is a small chance of getting a duplicate value from repeated calls to either random number call. Making them unique requires more work. If the set of numbers you want to draw from is small you can build a var array of numbers and remove one at a time randomly from the array.

The memory requirements of that get bad as the range of numbers gets large.

If you need a very large range of numbers but only need to generate a fairly small number of them you can add each number to a set of already-used numbers and then test each new number against the already-used numbers before returning it. That's fast and fairly memory-efficient until you generate thousands of unique numbers. It's memory requirements keep climbing. Sets test for membership quite fast, so that should be fine.

Can you give more details of your requirements?

Comment: Hey Duncan! Would you mind updating this to use the Swift 4 random APIs?

Comment: @Alexander, update what? my mention of `Int(rand())`? (So change that to `Int.random(in:)`?)

Comment: Yep! (If you think it’s a good idea. I didn’t edit directly, in case you had any reservations)

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you just want a UUID value, or equivalent unique value, stored as an Int - which you can do with the built in hashValue method:

`let g = UUID().hashValue`

This method is deterministic so you'll always get the same resulting integer when supplying the same UUID.

Comment: `.hashValue` isn't guaranteed to return the same hash between application launches (and it often doesn't)

Comment: This is over-complicated and slow. You should generate a random number directly, rather than deriving one from a random UUID.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to generate unique UInt value then this should work:

```
private static var counter: NSDecimalNumber = .zero

public static func uniqueUIntId() -> String {
    counter = counter.adding(.one)
    return counter.stringValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the following to generate unique ID values.

Provides unique integer ID values from 2

User should return unused ID's so IDGen can reclaim them

Returned ID positions are set to zero making reclaiming them easy to find

```swift
class IDGen {
    private var ids:[Int] = [1] // fill the first value so we dont have to test for empty

    func getID() -> Int {
        if let i = ids.firstIndex(where:{$0 == 0}) {
            let value = ids[i-1] + 1
            ids[i] = value
            return value
        }
        let ret = ids.last! + 1
        ids.append(ret)
        return ret
    }

    func returnID(_ id:Int) {
        if let i = ids.firstIndex(where:{$0 == id}) {
            ids[i] = 0
        }
    }

    func print(label:String) {
        Swift.print(label,ids)
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn’t thread safe, and linear scanning the full array each time is expensive. You sold use a Set or a bloom filter, instead.

Comment: Was not an issue in my case, I wanted to show a case where reclaimable unique integer values could be provided. Modify as you see fit for your purposes.

Comment: I think it's a bit misleading to present this solution without at least warning about these pretty serious trade-offs. Making something called "IDGen", and then having it be neither thread-safe, nor high throughput is pretty... odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can just generate a random integer directly:

```
Int.random(in: Int.min...Int.max)
```

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/random(in:)-9mjpw)

Answer (score -3):

Figured it out using:

```
Int(rand())
```

Comment: If you really need unique, this is going to fail. Sooner or later.

Comment: @MirekE this is true for any solution that generates random, finite-length values (including UUIDs). If you want it to *never* fail, you’ll need to use a sequence, or a history of all used IDs to make sure you never give the same one.